# How can I determine if a compiled Objective-C app is using garbage collection?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, garbage-collection

For any application that I have on my Mac, is there a way to tell if it was compiled with GC enabled, or if it's doing manual memory management?

Comment: I am curious why this is an interesting question.  Why would you care, as long as it's not leaky?

Comment: MacRuby is GC'd. If I'm going to inject MacRuby code directly into the app, it must be GC'd too. E.g. Mail plugins.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.douglaspurdy.com/2008/06/12/objective-c-20-garbage-collection/). Mind you that the original post is [wrong](http://www.douglaspurdy.com/2008/06/14/objective-c-20-garbage-collection-part-ii/), but contains a [comment](http://www.douglaspurdy.com/2008/06/12/objective-c-20-garbage-collection/#comment-46) by [Mark Rowe](http://bdash.net.nz/), an Apple engineer, that points the way.

I have re-run the `otool` commands he mentions on my machine with the current OS (10.6.4). Here's the output:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin meaningless.local 10.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0: Fri Apr 23 18:28:53 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.7.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

### Mail doesn't use GC
$ otool -oV /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail | tail -3
Contents of (__DATA,__objc_imageinfo) section
  version 0
    flags 0x0

### Xcode supports GC and retain/release
$ otool -oV /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode | tail -3
Contents of (__DATA,__objc_imageinfo) section
  version 0
    flags 0x2 OBJC_IMAGE_SUPPORTS_GC
```

[Mark Rowe's explanation](http://www.douglaspurdy.com/2008/06/12/objective-c-20-garbage-collection/#comment-46):

> The field of interest here is the “flags” field of the `__image_info` section of the `__OBJC` segment.
>   If garbage collection is supported it will have the value `0×2` and will be shown as “GC RR” to
>   represent that both garbage collection and retain/release are supported. If garbage collection
>   is *required* then the field will have the value `0×4` and will be shown as “GC-only” indicating
>   that only garbage collection is supported and that retain/release is not available. The field 
>   can also contain other values, but those two are the only values that are relevant to garbage collection.

Comment: On Lion, trying this on both ScreenSaverEngine and Xcode gives the result “flags 0x6 OBJC_IMAGE_SUPPORTS_GC”. I'm not sure which way to interpret that.

Comment: Peter, I think GC was initially required for 64-bit screen savers but only supported for 32-bit. Perhaps the flag reflects both in Lion.

Comment: Great stuff; Curiously, as of OSX 10.11 / Xcode 7.2, Xcode now reports `flags 0x0`( `otool -o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode | tail -1`). In fact, among all of Apple's standard apps (Mail, Reminders, Calendar, ...), only `System Preferences` reports `flags 0x2 OBJC_IMAGE_SUPPORTS_GC` on 10.11 - all others report `flags 0x0`. Do _Swift_-based executables report as that?

Answer (score 5):

Within the mach-o is a flag used to determine if a binary compiled with GC support, for non-GC, or mixed mode.

I don't know of anything that queries these bits via a more friendly API.

The [markgc.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/markgc.c) source within the Objective-C runtime can read said flags. You could refactor it to your needs, as desired.

Kind of curious why you need to know?

Comment: as for why, see my comment on the question after Chris's.

Comment: I don't think otool spews the needed info. Maybe so, though -- you'll have to parse the output.

Comment: oh but it does. see my answer.

Comment: Ooh... nice.  I'd forgotten that was added.