# JXA: Accessing CFString constants from CoreServices

Tags: objective-c, core-services, javascript-automation

[JXA](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW1), with its built-in ObjC bridge, exposes enumeration and constants from the `Foundation` framework automatically via the `$` object; e.g.:

```
$.NSUTF8StringEncoding  // -> 4
```

However, there are also useful `CFString` constants in lower-level APIs that aren't automatically imported, namely the `kUTType*` constants in `CoreServices` that define frequently-used [UTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Type_Identifier) values, such as [`kUTTypeHTML`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/UTI_Text_Types) for UTI `"public.html"`.

While you can *import* them with `ObjC.import('CoreServices')`, their *string value* isn't (readily) accessible, presumably because its type is `CFString[Ref]`:

```
ObjC.import('CoreServices') // import kUTType* constants; ObjC.import('Cocoa') works too
$.kUTTypeHTML  // returns an [object Ref] instance - how do you get its string value?
```

I have yet to find a way to get at the *string* at the heart of what's returned:
`ObjC.unwrap($.kUTTypeHTML)` doesn't work, and neither does `ObjC.unwrap($.kUTTypeHTML[0])` (nor `.deepUnwrap()`).

I wonder:

- if there's a native JXA way to do this that I'm missing.
- otherwise, if there's away to use `ObjC.bindFunction()` to define bindings for `CFString*()` functions that can solve the problem, such as to [`CFStringGetCString()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetCString) or [`CFStringGetCStringPtr()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetCStringPtr), but it's not obvious to me how to translate the ObjC signatures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't understand all implications, the following seems to work:

```
$.CFStringGetCStringPtr($.kUTTypeHTML, 0) // -> 'public.html'

# Alternative, with explicit UTF-8 encoding specification
$.CFStringGetCStringPtr($.kUTTypeHTML, $.kCFStringEncodingUTF8) // ditto
```

The `kUTType*` constants are defined as `CFStringRef`, and `CFStringGetCStringPtr` returns a `CFString` object's internal C string in the specified encoding, *if* it can be extracted ["with no memory allocations and no copying, in constant time"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetCStringPtr) - or `NULL` otherwise.

With the built-in constants, it seems that a C string (rather than `NULL`) is always returned, which - by virtue of C data types mapping onto JXA data types - is directly usable in JavaScript:

```
 $.CFStringGetCStringPtr($.kUTTypeHTML, 0) === 'public.html' // true
```

For **background** information (as of OSX 10.11.1), read on.

---

JXA doesn't natively recognize `CFString` objects, even though they can be "toll-free bridged" to `NSString`, a type that JXA *does* recognize.

You can verify that JXA does *not* know the equivalence of `CFString` and `NSString` by executing `$.NSString.stringWithString($.kUTTypeHTML).js`, which *should* return a copy of the input string, but instead fails with `-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Not recognizing `CFString` is our starting point: `$.kUTTypeHTML` is of type `CFString[Ref]`, but JXA doesn't return a *JS* string representation of it, only `[object Ref]`.

<sup>Note: The following is in part speculative - do tell me if I'm wrong.</sup>

Not recognizing `CFString` has another side effect, namely when invoking `CF*()` functions that accept a *generic* type (or Cocoa methods that accept a toll-free bridged `CF*` type that JXA is unaware of):
In such cases, **if the argument type doesn't exactly match the invoked function's parameter type, JXA apparently implicitly *wraps* the input object in a `CFDictionary` instance, whose only entry has key `type`, with the associated value containing the original object.**<sup>[1]</sup>

Presumably, this is why the above `$.NSString.stringWithString()` call fails: it is being passed the `CFDictionary` wrapper rather than the `CFString` instance.

Another case in point is the `CFGetTypeID()` function, which expects a `CFTypeRef` argument: i.e., *any* `CF*` type.

Since JXA doesn't know that it's OK to pass a `CFStringRef` argument as-is as the `CFTypeRef` parameter, it mistakenly performs the above-mentioned wrapping, and effectively passes a `CFDictionary` instance instead:

```
$.CFGetTypeID($.kUTTypeHTML) // -> !! 18 (CFDictionary), NOT 7 (CFString)
```

This is what [houthakker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1800086/houthakker) experienced in [his solution attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34023822/45375).

For a given `CF*` function you can *bypass* the default behavior by using `ObjC.bindFunction()` to *redefine* the function of interest:

```
// Redefine CFGetTypeID() to accept any type as-is:
ObjC.bindFunction('CFGetTypeID', ['unsigned long', [ 'void *']])
```

Now, `$.CFGetTypeID($.kUTTypeHTML)` correctly returns `7` (`CFString`).

<sup>Note: The redefined `$.CFGetTypeID()` returns a JS `Number` instance, whereas the original returns a *string* representation of the underlying number (`CFTypeID` value).</sup>

Generally, **if you want to know the specific type of a given `CF*` instance informally, use `CFShow()`**, e.g.:

```
$.CFShow($.kUTTypeHTML) // -> '{\n    type = "{__CFString=}";\n}'
```

<sup>Note: `CFShow()` returns nothing and instead prints directly to *stderr*, so you can't capture the output in JS.

You may redefine `CFShow` with `ObjC.bindFunction('CFShow', ['void', [ 'void *' ]])` so as not to show the wrapper dictionary.</sup>

For natively recognized CF* types - those that map onto JS primitives - you'll see the specific type directly (e.g., `CFBoolean` for `false`); for unknown - and therefore wrapped - instances, you'll see the wrapper structure as above - read on for more.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Running the following gives you an *idea* of **the wrapper object being generated by JXA** when passing an unknown type:

```
// Note: CFShow() prints a description of the type of its argument
//  directly to stderr.
$.CFShow($.kUTTypeHTML) // -> '{\n    type = "{__CFString=}";\n}'

// Alternative that *returns* the description as a JS string:
$.CFStringGetCStringPtr($.CFCopyDescription($.kUTTypeHTML), 0) // -> (see above)
```

Similarly, using the known-to-JXA equivalence of `NSDictionary` and `CFDictionary`,

```
ObjC.deepUnwrap($.NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary( $.kUTTypeHTML ))
```

returns `{"type":"{__CFString=}"}`, i.e., a JS object with property `type` whose value is at this point - after an ObjC-bridge call *roundtrip* - a mere *string* representation of what presumably was the original `CFString` instance.

---

[houthakker's solution attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34023822/45375) also contains a handy snippet of code to obtain the type *name* of a `CF*` instance as a string.

If we refactor it into a function and apply the necessary redefinition of `CFGetTypeID()`, we get the following, HOWEVER:

- A *hack* is needed to make it return a value predictably (see comments and source code)
- Even then a random character sometimes appears as the end of the string returned, such as `CFString,` rather than `CFString`.

<sup>If anyone has an explanation for why the hack is needed and where the random characters come from, please let me know. The issues may be memory-management related, as both `CFCopyTypeIDDescription()` and `CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation()` return an object that the *caller* must release, and I don't know whether/how/when JXA does that.</sup>

```js
/* 
  Returns the type name of the specified CF* (CoreFoundation) type instance.
  CAVEAT:
   * A HACK IS EMPLOYED to ensure that a value is consistently returned f
     those CF* types that correspond to JS primitives, such as CFNumber, 
     CFBoolean, and CFString:
     THE CODE IS CALLED IN A TIGHT LOOP UNTIL A STRING IS RETURNED.
     THIS SEEMS TO WORK WELL IN PRACTICE, BUT CAVEAT EMPTOR.
     Also, ON OCCASION A RANDOM CHARACTER APPEARS AT THE END OF THE STRING.
   * Only pass in true CF* instances, as obtained from CF*() function
     calls or constants such as $.kUTTypeHTML. Any other type will CRASH the
     function. 

  Example:
    getCFTypeName($.kUTTypeHTML) // -> 'CFString'  
*/
function getCFTypeName(cfObj) {

  // Redefine CFGetTypeID() so that it accepts unkown types as-is
  // Caution:
  //  * ObjC.bindFunction() always takes effect *globally*.
  //  * Be sure to pass only true CF* instances from then on, otherwise
  //    the function will crash.
  ObjC.bindFunction('CFGetTypeID', [ 'unsigned long', [ 'void *' ]])

  // Note: Ideally, we'd redefine CFCopyDescription() analogously and pass 
  // the object *directly* to get a description, but this is not an option:
  //   ObjC.bindFunction('CFCopyDescription', ['void *', [ 'void *' ]])
  // doesn't work, because, since we're limited to *C* types,  we can't describe
  // the *return* type in a way that CFStringGetCStringPtr() - which expects
  // a CFStringRef - would then recognize ('Ref has incompatible type').

  // Thus, we must first get a type's numerical ID with CFGetTypeID() and then
  // get that *type*'s description with CFCopyTypeIDDescription().
  // Unfortunately, passing the resulting CFString to $.CFStringGetCStringPtr()
  // does NOT work: it yields NULL - no idea why.
  // 
  // Using $.CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(), which yields a CFData
  // instance, from which a C string pointer can be extracted from with 
  // CFDataGetBytePtr(), works:
  //  - reliably with non-primitive types such as CFDictionary
  //  - only INTERMITTENTLY with the equivalent types of JS primitive types
  //    (such as CFBoolean, CFString, and CFNumber) - why??
  //    Frequently, and unpredictably, `undefined` is returned.
  // !! THUS, THE FOLLOWING HACK IS EMPLOYED: THE CODE IS CALLED IN A TIGHT
  // !! LOOP UNTIL A STRING IS RETURNED. THIS SEEMS TO WORK WELL IN PRACTICE,
  // !! BUT CAVEAT EMPTOR.
  //    Also, sometimes, WHEN A STRING IS RETURNED, IT MAY CONTAIN A RANDOM
  //    EXTRA CHAR. AT THE END.
  do {
    var data = $.CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(
            null, // use default allocator
            $.CFCopyTypeIDDescription($.CFGetTypeID(cfObj)), 
            0x08000100, // kCFStringEncodingUTF8
            0 // loss byte: n/a here
        ); // returns a CFData instance
    s = $.CFDataGetBytePtr(data)
  } while (s === undefined)
  return s
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can coerce a CF type to an NS type by first re-binding the CFMakeCollectable function so that it takes 'void *' and returns 'id', and then using that function to perform the coercion:

```
ObjC.bindFunction('CFMakeCollectable', [ 'id', [ 'void *' ] ]);

var cfString = $.CFStringCreateWithCString(0, "foo", 0); // => [object Ref]
var nsString = $.CFMakeCollectable(cfString);            // => $("foo")
```

To make this easier to use in your code, you might define a .toNS() function on the Ref prototype:

```
Ref.prototype.toNS = function () { return $.CFMakeCollectable(this); }
```

Here is how you would use this new function with a CFString constant:

```
ObjC.import('CoreServices')

$.kUTTypeHTML.toNS() // => $("public.html")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but can you explain what `CFMakeCollectable`'s true purpose is, and whether using it has any side effects in this case? And why does adding a function to the prototype of `Ref` make it available on `$.kUTTypeHtml`?  The prototype-modifying approach is convenient, but also treacherous.

Comment: Also, `toNS()` returns a _wrapped_ string; return `$.CFMakeCollectable(this).js;` fixes that.

Comment: `CFMakeCollectable` makes a newly-allocated Core Foundation object eligible for garbage collection.  When called in a non-garbage-collected process, it has no effect and just returns the object that was passed into it.

Comment: In your script, `$.kUTTypeHtml` is an instance of Ref. All functions and properties defined on `Ref.prototype` are available on instances of `Ref`. For more information, search for information on the 'JavaScript prototype inheritance chain'.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and explanations. Personally, given the need to call `ObjC.bindFunction` first and that I'd rather not modify prototypes, I'll stick with `$.CFStringGetCStringPtr($.kUTTypeHTML, 0)` - unless you see a problem with that.  One more question: Given that `kUTTypeHTML` is a _constant_, is it still safe to call `CFMakeCollectable` on it?

Comment: As I said, `CFMakeCollectable` has no effect when called in a non-garbage-collected process. Its lack of effect is not dependent on the type of argument passed to it; _constant_ or otherwise. In my testing it seemed to be safe.

Comment: Thanks; I guess I'm not clear on how the JavaScript side of things relates to the Objective-C garbage collection in this case.

Comment: JavaScript is garbage collected... but the Objective-C framework that implements JavaScript for Automation does not support Objective-C garbage collection, as can be seen from the output of this command: `otool -oV /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptAppleEvents.framework | tail -3`.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129925) question for more information.

Comment: Thanks again, that clarifies it (in case someone else reads this: the command was missing the final path component: should be `otool -oV /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptAppleEvents.framework/JavaScriptAppleEvents | tail - 3`).

Answer (score 1):

$.kUTTypeHTML appears to return a CFDictionary (see below), so you should find useable methods at:

EDIT: It turns out that some typing complexities in JXA-ObjC-CF interactions mean that snippet below is NOT a reliable or generally applicable approach to learning the type of a CF Object reference. (See the discussion that follows).

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/

```
ObjC.import('CoreServices')

var data = $.CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(
        null, 
        $.CFCopyTypeIDDescription(
            $.CFGetTypeID($.kUTTypeHTML)
        ), 
        'UTF-8',
        0
    ); // CFDataRef


cPtr = $.CFDataGetBytePtr(data);

// --> "CFDictionary"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but ultimately (a) I wasn't able to extract any meaningful value from treating `$.kUTTypeHTML` as a `CFDictionary` instance (via `$.NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary($.kUTTypeHTML)`, thanks to toll-free bridging with `NSDictionary`, which returned `"type":{__CFString=}`, from which I could extract no value), and (b) the documentation states that the actual type is `CFStringRef`, which I was eventually able to get to work in my answer - so I'm not sure that your snippet works as intended.

Comment: Thanks ! Your solution is very helpful. Apologies for the over optimistic diversion.

Comment: Not sure how to fix the type reporting: `$.CFGetTypeID($.kUTTypeHTML)` returns "18" rather than "7", and returns true on CFDictionary, as if JXA gets it through one additional level of indirection.

Comment: Perhaps this sheds light:  `$.NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary(
  $.kUTTypeHTML
 )
 
 --> $({"type":$("{__CFString=}")})`

Comment: Because this comment thread was getting too long, I've cleaned up my comments here and summarized the findings in an update to my answer. Note the use of `CFShow()` and my redefinition of `CFGetTypeID()` using `ObjC.bindFunction()` to get the former to report the true type of `$.kUTTypeHTML`; however, there are still loose ends - feel free to comment.